# How to allow Nginx with iptables (django)

Tags: django, nginx

I am making a site with django so I followed [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04) but I have an error in `/var/log/nginx/error.log` when I type my domain name in browser (502 bad gateway):

```
2019/05/15 11:13:05 [error] 1860#1860: *12 connect() to unix:/home/username/MYPROJECT/myproject.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: myproject.net, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/username/MYPROJECT/myproject.sock:/", host: "myproject.net"
```

I think the problem is because my iptables rules block nginx. So my question is:
What is the IPTABLES equivalent of `ufw allow 'Nginx Full'` ?

Answer (score 1):

For NGINX, you need to open port 80 (HTTP requests) and/or port 443 (HTTPS requests). So use the following commands:

**HTTP**

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

**HTTPS**

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 443 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

In case you want to open more, I recommend [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/iptables-essentials-common-firewall-rules-and-commands) for how to access most common services like MySQL etc from behind iptables.